# How to retrieve result set from postgres stored procedure(or function) using pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg, node-postgres

Hi I am working on a web app that uses postgres and some of the sql is in stored procedure/functon. If a function returns a cursor, how can we retrieve and process the resultset in nodejs? I am using pg (node-postgres). Following is the code for the test procedure that I would like to call from nodejs code.

```
drop table if exists tmp;
create table tmp
(
  x integer
);
drop function if exists t1;

create or replace function t1( p_value integer)
returns refcursor
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
  ref refcursor;
begin
  --insert into tmp(x) values(p_value);
  open ref for select x from tmp;
  return ref;
end
$$;
```

Comment: Change that into a set returning function and your life will be a lot easier. You don't even need PL/pgSQL for this.

Comment: Hi, my goal is to return result set so I can process it row by row in the middle tier. This is possible from other languages and.I was wondering if nodejs pg allows this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how this is done in Postgres. Change it to a set-returning function:

```
create or replace function t1(p_value integer)
   returns table (x integer) --<< adjust here for the real column list
language sql
as $$
  insert into tmp(x) values(p_value)
  returning x; --<< adjust here for the real column list
$$;
```

Then use it as part of a SELECT statement:

```
select *
from t1(42);
```

Obviously the `42` can be a parameter from your programming language.

Comment: Thank you. If there was no insert statement (from which you are returning the set, how would you do it? I will try this with the "table" returning method a bit later and if that works will confirm this as the answer.

Comment: What else would you have instead of an INSERT?

Comment: Hi, Just imagine the procedure WITHOUT the insert. The data has been inserted elsewhere and I need to retrieve the data.

Comment: Then use a `SELECT`